# Eloquent: order by relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have three tables: products, product_prices and pricing_types

pricing_types structure:

- id
- name
- percent

For example, user (admin) can add pricing type for individuals and set percent to 100. Like X costs 100$, but for guys like me and you it will be 200.
For companies ['respectable' guys like not me and you] they will create another pricing_type with percent 30 or so. This way, each product may have mupltiple prices (for different groups).

product_prices_structure:

- id
- value
- pricing_type_id
- product_id

products structure:

- id
- name
- image

So, i need to order products by price.
Each product may have multiple prices (for individuals, companies, aliens etc)

What i am tried:

```
$q = Product::join('product_prices', function (JoinClause $join) {
    $join->on('product_prices.product_id', '=', 'products.id');
})->with(['category', 'prices', 'prices.pricingTypes'])->orderBy('product_prices.value', 'ASC')->simplePaginate(20)->withQueryString();
```

But it is not working

Also this also not working (and shouldnt i guess):

```
Product::with(['prices' => function ($q) {
    return $q->orderBy('value', 'ASC');
}], 'prices.pricingTypes')->simplePaginate(20)->withQueryString();
```

Comment: can you post sample json result for `Product::select('id')->with('prices')->take(5)->get();`

Comment: @silver https://gist.github.com/callback9/5dd0e1d776c4855fee58a989ed082efa

Comment: so which price is the priority for ordering? you have arrays of prices and you cannot use array as order, you either sum the values, get the min or max or single item from the array.

Comment: assume this `{"id":153,"prices":[{"value":23},{"value":2},{"value":26}]}` and `{"id":155,"prices":[{"value":24},{"value":21}, {"value":25}]}` which one is the priority? `153` or `155` ? and based on what?

Comment: @silver well, lets say inidividual price is priority, example there https://gist.github.com/callback9/50b57c2efc631b31e187a3253f914d1f

Comment: @i am sorry, updated my question. So now ->with['pricingTypes']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the info you've provided you can order your query like this;

```
Product::select(
    'products.*',
    DB::raw('COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN pt.is_individual = true THEN pr.value END), 0) as price_sort')
)
    ->leftJoin('product_prices as pr', 'products.id', '=', 'pr.product_id')
    ->leftJoin('pricing_types as pt', 'pr.id', '=', 'pt.pricing_type_id')
    ->orderBy('price_sort')
    ->simplePaginate(20)
    ->withQueryString();
```

The idea is to have another select column to be use for ordering using the price value where additional relationship `is_individual` is `true`

```
DB::raw('COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN pt.is_individual = true THEN pr.value END), 0) as price_sort')
```

Comment: Thank you! But there is a problem, it says 'Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pt.price_id' '

Comment: I think that supposed to be `pt.pricing_type_id`, just double check the table names and column names on join and select